# popup fancybox/thickbox in user control

Tags: jquery, asp.net, user-controls, fancybox, thickbox

i'm try to use thickbox or fancybox popup in asp.net
when i use this on aspx page it's work well.
but when i use it in gridview it's not work.

i use below code in user control,and it's work well,

```
 <a class="thickbox" href="Default.aspx??txtid=1&keepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&height=100&width=100'">Default.aspx</a>
```

btu when ther gridview is bind, popup dosen't work

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvResult" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="WordID" runat="server">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div style="float: right">

                                <asp:Image ID="Image1" Width="115" Height="100" ImageUrl='<%# string.Format("../Upload/Images/{0}",Eval("IsExistPic")) %>' runat="server" />
                            </div>
                            <div style="float: right">
                                <a class="thickbox"  href="../test.aspx?txtid=1&keepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&height=500&width=600">Default.aspx</a>

                                <asp:HyperLink ID="various2" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#string.Format("../LogIn.aspx?txtid=1&keepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&height=500&width=600") %>'><img src="../img/sound.png" /></asp:HyperLink>
                                <br />
                                <asp:HyperLink ID="hplfilm" runat="server"><img src="../img/film.png" /></asp:HyperLink>
                                <br />
                                <asp:HyperLink ID="hplpronun" runat="server"><img src="../img/microphone.png" /></asp:HyperLink>
                                <br />
                                <asp:HyperLink ID="hplinfo" NavigateUrl="../Default.aspx" runat="server"><img src="../img/info.png" /></asp:HyperLink>
                                <br />
                                <asp:HyperLink ID="hplReport" NavigateUrl="../Default.aspx" runat="server"><img src="../img/repo.png" /></asp:HyperLink>
                                <br />
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: are you opening images only or html content or external pages? if the first, check http://fancybox.net/faq No.6

Comment: i use user control inside default.aspx with masterpage